# How can I do this dynamically?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am working on writing my code this way, but I want to do it in a loop. I want to be dynamic. How can I do it?

```
$("#sound-player").attr("src",secilen[0]);
var x = document.getElementById("sound-player");
x.play();
x.onended = function() {
  $("#sound-player").attr("src",secilen[1]);
  var x = document.getElementById("sound-player");
  x.play();
  x.onended = function() {
    $("#sound-player").attr("src",secilen[2]);
    var x = document.getElementById("sound-player");
    x.play();
    x.onended = function() {
      $("#sound-player").attr("src",secilen[3]);
      var x = document.getElementById("sound-player");
      x.play();
      x.onended = function() {
        alert("bitti");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reuse your variable `x`, instead o redefining it.

```
var player = document.getElementById('sound-player');
var i = 0;

function playSource(src){
    // change the src attribute and play.
    if (secilen[scr] !== undefined) {
        player.setAttribute('src', secilen[src]);
        player.play();
    }
    else {
        alert('bitti')
    }
}

player.onended = function(){
    i++;
    playSource(i);
}

playSource(i); //start playing the first sound
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion:

```js
/* Cache the player. */
var x = document.getElementById("sound-player");

/* Create an IIFE and execute it recursively. */
(function playRecursively (current, last) {
    x.src = secilen[current];
    x.play();
    x.onended = function() {
        /* Play the next, if the current is not the last. */
        if (current < last) playRecursively(++current, last);
        else alert("bitti");
    };
})(0, secilen.length - 1);
```